# Office 365 API - Getting Licensing Information: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user's product license information with this query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/dmsarktrial.onmicrosoft.com/subscribedSkus

and get an error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". I set a bearer and other queries that require authentication do work. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the test, the Microsoft Graph REST need the scope of `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. You can grant the scope like figure below:
[image]

Comment: Actually "Read directory data" (or directory.read.all) should provide the same capability.  This will give your app least privileged access to Graph.  Looks like we also need to update this topic: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_get with that information.